# Hybrid android app

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I'm trying to develop a Hybrid android app where all by logic to get the data will be in Java and the presentation layer will be HTML embedded in a webview.

**My question here is, how to pass the collected data in Java to the HTML in side a webview? Collected data will be of a Java collections type.. like a map.**

Option I considered, but DONT want to use

1) **PhoneGap** kind of solutions - as I'm using some native hardware access features which PhoeGap doesnt support yet.

2) Hosting my Java logic as a server side logic for HTML and build presentation layer in server side itself(like using JSP)

Comment: Just to get my mind around what you want: why do you feel the need for HTML/webview for the "presentation layer"?

Comment: Why can't you use PhoneGap and write your own plug-in for the missing hardware component?

Comment: It's looks like you're simply don't want to study XML

Comment: @biovamp I understand that we can pass it as an XML string from Java and phrase it in JS to present it. I'm trying to understand if there is a way to build the HTML hand on hand like in JSP.

Comment: @Nanne I'm trying to build HTML for presentation as I'm more familiar with it than the Native one. Especially when the presentation is something more than a text view or list view, I'm trying to leverage the easy formatting and styling using HTML 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look [at the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). Especially the Basic Usage section which says

> // OR, you can also load from an HTML string:
>      String summary =
>   `"<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points.</body></html>";`
>
> webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);

Comment: Thanks for answering. Building HTML itself in the Java and passing string is an option. I'm not preferring it as my HTML will be considerably larger and will be messing if I build it in Java.  Consider if I have my HTML files stored inside the project, can I pass and loop through the Java objects inside the HTML file, like in JSP? I know it sounds strange to expect Java object inside HTML.. just trying to understand if there is an option in android world.